# How to convert this query to yii query?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want this Sql command to converted into yii cactivedataprovider format so that I can feed dataprovider with this criteria.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (

    SELECT (

    CASE WHEN product_name LIKE '%nokia%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE WHEN product_name LIKE '%lumia%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE WHEN product_name LIKE '%800%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS numMatches, product_name
    FROM Production
    ) AS t
    WHERE numMatches >0
    ORDER BY numMatches DESC
```

Comment: Have you tried the `CSqlDataProvider` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider? Or is this not an option?

Comment: I strictly need CActiveDataProvider as it'll be getting passed to a widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment about needing a `ActiveDataProvider` is likely not true, most Yii widgets just need an instance of [`CDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider) which both SQLDataProvider and ActiveDataProvider are. If you **really** need active record models though, you can select active record models via SQL with:

```
$models = MyModel::model()->findAllBySql($sql);
```

And then use them in a data provider like this:

```
$data = CArrayDataProvider($models);
```

Comment: $sql will be the raw mysql command that I just have given?

Comment: Yes, it will then parse the results into ActiveRecord models.